# Applying stateListAnimator in RecylerView's item will cause flickering effect when calling notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android

I realize, if I apply `android:stateListAnimator` on `RecylerView`'s item, calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` will cause undesired flickering effect on certain `RecylerView`'s items (Not all items, strangely)

Here's my RecylerView's item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/lift_up"
    android:background="@drawable/white" >

    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

`@anim/lift_up` is defined as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="8dip"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="4dip"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

and `@drawable/white` is defined as

```
<drawable name="white">#ffffffff</drawable>
```

When I call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`, the following strange flickering effect happens at the last 5 items of RecylerView. (There are total 10 visible items on screen)

https://youtu.be/yB4UP2wEFk0

This problem only happen at API 21 and above, because only API 21 supports `android:stateListAnimator`

Is this a bug, or I had missed out something?

The complete minimal workable code can be downloaded from https://github.com/yccheok/RecyclerViewTutorial/tree/4763879598864233a8e6544fe240c3fb34a15b73

Comment: Maybe you can use animator on Recyclerview instead.

Comment: @tinysunlight Applying animator at Recyclerview doesn't help in anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Not all items, strangely**

This is by design (I believe).

Internally, all *recycling* ViewGroups (that I have dealt with) maintain a View pool. Its expensive to create a View from scratch. Some of this cost is dissipated by using a View pool, at the expense of resource usage. Size of this pool represents this tradeoff. A basic implementation can be looked at here: [ViewPool from DeckView](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/DeckView/blob/master/deckview/src/main/java/com/appeaser/deckview/views/ViewPool.java).

`RecyclerView` does the same with [RecycledViewPool](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/support/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#RecycledViewPool). Note the default max size:

```
public static class RecycledViewPool {
    ....
    private static final int DEFAULT_MAX_SCRAP = 5;
    ....
}
```

I believe the first 5 views in your case don't flicker because they come from the pool - they're not created when `notifyDataSetChanged()` call is made. This might be the reason that the `StateListAnimator` does not kick in. For the rest 5 rows/items, new Views are created.

From the source code:

```
View getViewForPosition(int position, boolean dryRun) {
    ....
    // 0) If there is a changed scrap, try to find from there
    ....
    // 1) Find from scrap by position
    ....
    // 2) Find from scrap via stable ids, if exists
    ....
    // fallback to recycler
        ....
        // getRecycledViewPool() returns an instance of RecycledViewPool
        holder = getRecycledViewPool().getRecycledView(type);
        ....
    // if holder is still 'null' after checking the pool, create a new one
        ....
        if (holder == null) {
            holder = mAdapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.this, type);
        }
        ....
}
```

As you can tell, *recycling* is a serious business. What I cannot explain is *why* options `0, 1, and 2` fail - or tell if they even do. To check my hypothesis, you can change the pool's `max` size and note any difference(s) (in the # of views that flicker):

```
mRecyclerView
    .getRecycledViewPool()
        .setMaxRecycledViews(RecyclerView.INVALID_TYPE, 10);
```

Comment: At first glance, it seems like is caused by incorrect view recycling. However, after I add `setMaxRecycledViews`, the outcome is still the same. This last views are still having flickering effect.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I see. The only other reason I can think of is related to view caching. `RecyclerView` caches Views as well. In the code posted above, `RecyclerViewPool` supplies Views on step 3. From your sample project, step 2 will not happen since your adapter does not have stable ids. That leaves Step 0 & 1. Unfortunately, I don't think Step 0 & 1 are verifiable. You're welcome to go through the source code and discover something that I missed.

Comment: by using `setHasStableIds(true)` and `this.items.get(position).getId()` in `getItemId(int position)`. I manage to make the flickering problem gone. https://github.com/yccheok/RecyclerViewTutorial/tree/114684d741270b11e9d556d8b883e729c52944cc But, any idea why it is so?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I took your sample project for a trial run. Using the debugger, I have confirmed what I said above - `I believe the first 5 views in your case don't flicker because they come from the pool`. The mistake I made was telling you to try `mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(RecyclerView.INVALID_TYPE, 10);`. The constant `RecyclerView.INVALID_TYPE` holds the value `-1` whereas the default implementation of `getItemViewType()` returns `0`. This is why you did not see any difference. Please try the above mentioned call with arguments `(0, 10)`.

Comment: Hi Vikram, using arguments (0, 10) works for me. Any idea, on how not to hard code value 10? Is there any dynamic way to determine best value for ? (0, ?)

Comment: @CheokYanCheng `?` should be equal to the number of views that are visible. Using this information, I would say that `?` should be equal to `mRecyclerView.getChildCount()`. The only boundary case I can think of - when the number of items is small and they _don't_ fill the screen completely. In this case, `? == mRecyclerView.getChildCount() && ? == mAdapter.getItemCount()`. Why is this a boundary case - If the number of items increase (new items are added), `?` will have to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you check documentation of recyclerview method notifyDataSetChanged in http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/support/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java for method notifyDatasetChanged, it mentions following "

`RecyclerView` will attempt to synthesize visible structural change events
          for adapters that report that they have {@link #hasStableIds() stable IDs} when
          this method is used. This can help for the purposes of animation and visual
          object persistence but individual item views will still need to be rebound
          and relaid out.

Similar idea is sketched out also in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MIfSxgsHIs where you would do stableIds true if you had to do animations for list view, also more examples in the above mentioned dev bytes series assume stable ids for animation persistence in list items.