# Can adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemCount) replace adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()?

Tags: java, android

For `Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> adapter`, using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` may lead to undesired outcome. For instance

[Applying stateListAnimator in RecylerView's item will cause flickering effect when calling notifyDataSetChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851370/applying-statelistanimator-in-recylerviews-item-will-cause-flickering-effect-wh)

I was wondering, can we use `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemCount)` to replace `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`?

As I just tested, `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemCount)` will able to update all items properly, and cause no flickering.

What might be some potential problem, if we use `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemCount)` to replace `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: One of the major differences among `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemCount)` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is that, `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemCount)` will cause `onBindViewHolder` execute in visible & invisible items.. `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` will cause `onBindViewHolder` only execute in visible items.